# Disable options in drop-down if selected value matches using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, disabled-control

I have a drop-down list which contains duplicated values. Now i want to disable the options, which matches to the selected value.

Comment: Add some code , show what you try and where is a problem ?

Comment: Why don't you remove the duplicates before binding itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.prop('disabled',true);` element can be disabled. Please check below snippet to get idea how to make all other options with same value can make disabled.

```js
$('#duplicate').on('change',function(){
$(this).find('option').prop('disabled',false);  
$(this).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="duplicate">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to populate the drop down list with dupicate values? That is just confusing.

If you need to have duplicate values in the dropdown for any reason. Please explain in more detail why and maybee an example.

If you do not need to have duplicate values, then you should defenetly sort out the dupicate values **before** populating the dropdown

Comment: Actually my drop down values coming from a 3rd party api. Some option's values are same but text are different. So when i select an option, the option with same value in drop down should disable.